# swipeable divs that snap to screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I'm developing an cordova app with 3 "pages". The "pages" are divs with a fixed height and the with of 100%. (see div1, div2, div3 in the picture)

I'm currently using jquery show and hide functions with a slide but the performance on mobile phones is very bad. So I thought of using css, I cant get an idea of how to make is so you can swipe the current visible div to sort of snap the next div in place.

Maybe this picture wil clear my story up: [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqOEl.jpg)

I hope someone can push me in the right direction css and javascript wise..

Comment: By snap do you mean like an ease-in?

Comment: I belive by 'snap' author means that next div fill stop swipe animation right where previous div was - not free scrolling (swiping). See my answer below.

Comment: @aug more like if you swipe div2(see the picture) for more than half of its with out of the screen to the right div1 will slide to the center of the phone.

Comment: @Artanis I think u got what I mean.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still use jQuery Mobile to detect swipe left/right events on each div, but instead of animating div's position, you should add/remove class for the previous/active/next DIV. Classes should look something like this:

```
.container {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940); // this will add nice inertia effect upon switching DIVs
}

.container.previous {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.container.active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
.container.next {
   transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

Comment: Thats what I needed!! thank you so much. I'm working on a jsfiddle example and I will post it in a sec.

Comment: Looks and feels nice, also perfectly smooth - just tried on old iPhone 3G used for mobile performance testing :)